# Считывание страницы с Google Maps

Tags: php, google-maps-api

Если зайти на страницу вручную - возвращается JSON массив:

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $adres . '';
```

Вариант 1. Ругается, что не может распарсить, вне зависимости от того, используется ли `http` или `https`:

```
$thispage = file_get_contents($url);
```

Вариант 2. Просто пусто:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$thispage = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Как правильно считать страницы с Google Maps?

Comment: echo file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Москва,Тверская,10'); нормально отработало.

Comment: Проверьте в какой кодировке отправляете адрес. Должно быть UTF-8. Если передавать, например, в Windows-1251 - то да, ругается на INVALID_REQUEST.